# Get a strange "syntax error" when i'm trying to insert into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameter-passing

I'm trying to add a new row into a table I have. The database is a MSSQL. I have some other tables that have been working just fine, but when I did a new one I cant add new rows to it. Instead I get this error message:

"An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'."

I have no idea why...

the code in VS2013 lookes like this

```
        public void Update_Admin(User User)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Admin (User, Password) VALUES (@User, @Password);", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = User.UserName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = User.Password;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

I know that the values that come in is true. Anyone knows whts wrong?

the table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Admin] (
[Id]       INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[User]     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Password] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

);

Comment: I don't think mssql gets upset over keywords; however, just in case have you tried putting brackets around User and Password in your insert statement? "INSERT INTO Admin ([User], [Password])..." at least to eliminate one possible cause

Comment: You really should not be storing passwords in plain text. They should be salted and hashed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape the word `User`:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Admin ([User], Password) VALUES (@User, @Password);", con))
```

Comment: can yet, need to wait for another 9min :P Joao Leal was to fast to solve my problem :P